# Kafka connect Stream data from mongodb to elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am trying to stream data from mongodb to elasticsearch using kafka connect.

The data that is stream into kafka by mongodb connector is as given below

```
{
   "updatedAt" : {
      "$date" : 1591596275939
   },
   "createdAt" : {
      "$date" : 1362162600000
   },
   "name" : "my name",
   "_id" : {
      "$oid" : "5ee0cc7e0c3273f3d4a3c20f"
   },
   "documentId" : "mydoc1",
   "age" : 20,
   "language" : "English",
   "validFrom" : {
      "$date" : 978307200000
   },
   "remarks" : [
      "remarks"
   ],
   "married" : false
}
```

**I have below two problem while saving data to elasticsearch**

1. _id is an object and I want to use "documentId" key as _id instead in elasticsearch
2. Dates are an object with $date key which I cant't figure out how we can convert to normal date.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction regarding above two issues.

**Mongodb source config**

```
{
   "tasks.max" : "5",
   "change.stream.full.document" : "updateLookup",
   "name" : "mongodb-source",
   "value.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
   "collection" : "collection",
   "poll.max.batch.size" : "1000",
   "connector.class" : "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
   "batch.size" : "1000",
   "key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
   "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
   "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
   "connection.uri" : "mongodb://connection",
   "publish.full.document.only" : "true",
   "database" : "databasename",
   "poll.await.time.ms" : "5000",
   "topic.prefix" : "mongodb"
}
```

**Elastic sink config**

```
{
   "write.method" : "upsert",
   "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable" : "true",
   "name" : "elasticsearch-sink",
   "connection.password" : "password",
   "topic.index.map" : "mongodb.databasename.collection:elasticindexname",
   "connection.url" : "http://localhost:9200",
   "errors.log.enable" : "true",
   "flush.timeout.ms" : "20000",
   "errors.log.include.messages" : "true",
   "key.ignore" : "false",
   "type.name" : "_doc",
   "key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
   "value.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
   "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
   "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
   "tasks.max" : "1",
   "batch.size" : "100",
   "schema.ignore" : "true",
   "schema.enable" : "false",
   "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
   "read.timeout.ms" : "6000",
   "connection.username" : "elastic",
   "topics" : "mongodb.databasename.collection",
   "proxy.host": "localhost",
   "proxy.port": "8080"
}
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: MAP is not supported as the document id.
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.DataConverter.convertKey(DataConverter.java:107)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.DataConverter.convertRecord(DataConverter.java:182)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.tryWriteRecord(ElasticsearchWriter.java:291)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.write(ElasticsearchWriter.java:276)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.put(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:174)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:538)
        ... 10 more
```

**Connector Links :**

```
https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/master/kafka-source/
https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch
```

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have updated it in the question

Comment: Thanks. Any error logs from connect server or your connectors? What data do you see in the topics?

Comment: Have you considered adding Kafka Streams or KSQL to massage the data rather than just go from one database to another?

Comment: I have added the exception as well. And regarding kafka streams/ KSQL, I want to avoid any complexity. I want it to be a simple kafka connect setup of producer -> kafka -> consumer.

Comment: Very common it is never that easy, unfortunately

Comment: You will want to look at the unwrap transformation provided by Debezium for flattening the ID field. Otherwise, use a steam processor in the middle, writing back into Kafka, from where the sink pulls

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestions @OneCricketeer. Using kafka connect is adding complexity and taking more time then I expected. I think it is best to write custom consumer and producer.